# Sublime text – configuration to focus selections right away while searching

Tags: macos, sublime-text-2, textmate

Transitioning from Textmate to Sublime text and sorely missing one feature:

In textmate, when searching for "sometext" in a single file, "Cmd–g" sets focus to selection, so that you can edit current line with "sometext" occurrence in it without having to click on it first.

In sublime text, it selects "sometext" on that line, but you have to click to set cursor there which wastes my time and attention. Instead after pressing "Cmd–g" focus remains in search box and typing there changes search terms.

Is there a setting that I don't know of to allow that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found a workaround.

Apparently there are two different modes of search:
- Incremental search (cmd–i), and
- Find (cmd-f)

cmd-i does exactly what I need, so I switched shortcuts in my
Preferences->Key Bindings (User) from:

```
{ "keys": ["super+i"], "command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "incremental_find", "reverse":false} },
{ "keys": ["super+shift+i"], "command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "incremental_find", "reverse":true} },
{ "keys": ["super+f"], "command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "find"} },
```

to:

```
{ "keys": ["super+f"], "command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "incremental_find", "reverse":false} },
{ "keys": ["super+shift+f"], "command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "incremental_find", "reverse":true} },
//{ "keys": ["super+f"], "command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "find"} },
```

Hope that helps someone ))